# Chain Actions in an Effect in @ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am having some trouble chaining actions one after the other in an Effect that makes an HTTP-request.

Here's the Effect code:

```
export class UserEffects {

    @Effect()
    update$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(user.USERCHANGE).pipe(
        switchMap(data => this.authService.login(data['payload'])),
        map(userInfo => new UserChangedAction(userInfo)),
        tap(() => this.store.dispatch(
             new LoginStateChangeAction(localStorage.getItem('token')))
        )
    );

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private actions$: Actions,
        public store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {}
}
```

The problem is both the actions are being called simultaneously. The LoginStateChange action depends on UserChanged action to complete.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: try `concatMap` operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return multiple actions as explained in Austin's post: [Dispatching Multiple Actions from NGRX Effects](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22)

```
@Effect()
update$ = this.actions$.ofType(user.USERCHANGE).pipe(
  switchMap(data => this.authService.login(data['payload'])),
  switchMap(userInfo => [
    new UserChangedAction(userInfo),
    new LoginStateChangeAction(localStorage.getItem('token')),
  ])
);
```

Comment: I guess I didn't try enough. I think this is going to work. I'll test and accept if it does, soon.

Comment: And then, is there a way to do something inside lets say "tap" operator, after both 

    new UserChangedAction(userInfo),
    new LoginStateChangeAction(localStorage.getItem('token')), 

completes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try such combination - `UserChangedAction.switchMapTo(LoginStateChangeAction).pipe(stuff)`. It will wait for `UserChangedAction` emit and pnly after that will wait for `LoginStateChangeAction` emit. So it will be one by one.