# Chain Actions in an Effect ngrx v8

Tags: ngrx-effects

I want to chain effects with the latest syntax of `ngrx`. I've searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815427/chain-actions-in-an-effect-in-ngrx) question on stackoverflow but it has old syntax.

This is the current effect:

```
export class DeleteCommentEffect {

deleteComment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(DeletingComment),
        mergeMap((action) => this.commentService.deleteComment(action.dossierId, action.commentId)
            .pipe(
                map((statusCode: number) => {
                    return DeleteCommentSuccess({ statusCode });
                }),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    return of(DeleteCommentError({ error }));
                })
        ))
    )
);

constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private commentService: DBCommentService) {
}
```

}

I want to chain this effect after successfully delete a comment.

```
export class GetCommentEffects {
getComment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(GettingComment),
        mergeMap(action =>
            this.commentService.getAllComments(action.dossierId).pipe(
                map((comments: Comment[]) => {
                    return GetCommentSuccess({comments});
                }),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    return of(GetCommentError({error}));
                })
            ))
    )
);

constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private commentService: DBCommentService
) {}
```

}

I've searched in [ngrx docs](https://ngrx.io/docs) but it seems like it does not mention about how to chain effects.

Answer (score 1):

Create an effect that listens for `DeleteCommentSuccess` action that dispatches `GettingComment`.

```
deleteCommentSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DeleteCommentSuccess),
    map(() => CommentActions.GettingComments())
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any problem but this is essentially the purpose of side effects in that they handle the various side effects of your app. You can also trigger them using ngrx-router as well which would listen for certain route changes that then dispatch certain actions

Comment: Sorry for replying late, your solution works. Thank you.